# Computing the Stabilizer of a coset $Nh$ in $H=N.G$ using GAP.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, gap, group-extensions

Let **$H=N.G$ be an extension** of $N$ by $G$ and **$Nh$, $h\in H$, a **coset** of $N$ in $H$.** How do one  compute the **stabilizer $S$ of $Nh$ in $H$** using **GAP**?

Comment: There's a [section on stabilisers](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap41.html#X797BD60E7ACEF1B1) in the GAP manual.

Comment: How did you represent $H$? And what action? (conjugacy? Right multiplication?)

Comment: The action is by conjugacy.

Comment: H is represented  as a permutation group.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to calculate is the full pre-image of the centralizer in the factor group. You can either go through a natural homomorphism:

```
gap> H:=SymmetricGroup(4);;
gap> N:=Core(H,SylowSubgroup(H,2));;h:=(1,2);; # E.g. V4 in S4
gap> nat:=NaturalHomomorphismByNormalSubgroup(H,N);
[ (1,2,3,4), (1,2) ] -> [ f1*f2, f1 ]
gap> cen:=Centralizer(Image(nat),Image(nat,h));
Group([ f1 ])
gap> s:=PreImage(nat,cen);
Group([ (3,4), (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4) ])
gap> Size(s);
8
```

or use the dedicated function `CentralizerModulo`:

```
gap> s:=CentralizerModulo(H,N,h);
Group([ (3,4), (1,4)(2,3), (1,3)(2,4) ])
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.